# JQuery menu trigger content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with a bunch of list items. What I am trying to do is toggle a "highlight" class for which ever one the use clicks on it will change its properties.

Now the problem I am having is when the user clicks on one and makes it the active one when he/she clicks on the active one again it reverts back to its original state but changes all of  the other list items to the "highlight" class properties. I would like to make it so that it doesnt change the properties of the active one already and doesnt change the other list items either unless of course they want to click on the other list item then that previous active one reverts back and the new one changes. Code below.

```
    .highlight { background:black; color:white }

<ul id="momslist">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""/></a>
    <p>Name 4</p></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""/></a>
    <p>Name 3</p></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""/></a>
    <p>Name 2</p></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""/></a>
    <p>Name 1</p></li>
</ul>


$('#momslist li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    siblings = parent.siblings(),
    isOn = parent.toggleClass('highlight').hasClass('highlight');

    siblings.toggleClass('highlight', !isOn);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your !isOn - that's going to do the opposite - ie turn everything on when you turn that one off.

The following should work for what I think you're attempting: it makes sure that everything is turned off and turns on just the one you're interested in.

```
$('#momslist li a').click(function() {
    $('#momslist li').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
});
```

If you're interested in the "click once to turn on/click again to turn off", the following will do that

```
$('#momslist li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (parent.hasClass('highlight')) {
        parent.removeClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $('#momslist li').removeClass('highlight');
        parent.addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but should I be listening for the click on the li item rather than the link itself? I seem to have an issue when the user misses the link and clicks directly on the li item it doesnt change the class properties.

Comment: We would need to see your CSS in order to help with that. Perhaps a link to all the sample code would help?

Comment: Oh, and this is a more direct method. An answer via a different approach than your question. But fwiw, I voted for @SheldonGriffin 's answer. --Cannot get name linking to work. Grr.

Comment: Hmm... okay I got it working, targeting the toggle only when the image is clicked rather than the link. Now the question I have is is it possible to target just the specific <p> tag text associated with that list item and change the properties of that only, when the image is clicked?

Comment: Sure, if you wanted to - though I'd be inclined to get rid of the paragraphs altogether, and add the text to the link tags, after the images. Assuming you're attached to the <p>s, you would just change the selector to e.g. '#momslist li p' and, generally, parent() to next().

Comment: like this? 
    $('#momslist li img').click(function() {
     $('#momslist li p').removeClass('highlight');
     $(this).next().addClass('highlight');});

Answer (score 1):

The approach in the question seems like a lot of dom traversal, but perhaps the most direct solution would be to check to see if the parent has the highlight class on click, if so - don't do anything.

```
$('#momslist li a').click(function() {

    var parent = $(this).parent();

    if (parent.hasClass('highlight')) {return false;}//bail if highlighted

    siblings = parent.siblings(),
    isOn = parent.toggleClass('highlight').hasClass('highlight');
    siblings.toggleClass('highlight', !isOn);

});
```